# Нахождение n-го члена последовательности. Проблема - бесконечный цикл

Tags: c++, c, алгоритм, математика

Цикл получается бесконечным, потому что |an-an-1| возрастает, а не убывает. В чем проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
const double e = 0.0001;
int n = 0;
double an1;
double an = 0.0;

 do 
 {
    ++n;
    an1 = an;
    an = n*(sqrt(pow(n,2)+2*n)-2*(sqrt(pow(n,2)+n)+n));
} 

while (fabs(an - an1) >= e);
```

Comment: `an = n * (sqrt(pow(n, 2) + 2 * n) - 2 * sqrt(pow(n, 2) + n) + n);` была лишняя скобка, к тому же в while должно быть просто `>`.

Comment: Cпасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
an = n * (sqrt(pow(n, 2) + 2 * n) - 2 * sqrt(pow(n, 2) + n) + n);
```

Была лишняя скобка. Спасибо [@Drawn Raccoon](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/276430/drawn-raccoon) за ответ в комментариях!